# How To Copy Tables And Their Specific Columns To Another Database in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have huge sized Oracle Db, and for reporting, queries are working too slow because of the network traffic. The data warehouse tools are expensive so that I have decided to create a new database and feed it from the main database in every quarter. I was fresh in the company and I am not working as a DBA, so I have worked on 48 different SQL queries to detect which Db tables and columns are using for reporting and finished. Now I know which Db tables and columns are using. At that stage, I wanted to ask the best methods to create a new database with the same tables and columns names with the data of the main database?

Comment: Not quite clear with your requirement. But you can take a db dump with Import of Selected Tables and export it to the new database.

Comment: In fact, I thought that but I don't want whole tables and columns I want to migrate specific tables' specific columns to new Db.

Comment: Create the `DB link` between those two DBs and create the table in target DB using the CTAS on specific tables and specific columns.

Comment: Yes as suggested by @Tejash you can do that, or you can create temporary tables for your requirement in the same DB with the selected columns and export them. But that would cause a lot of overhead. Hence a much better approach would be to create a `DBLINK` and transfer the data depending on the volume of data.

Answer (score 1):

1. On Target (where tables need to be created) login as DBA user and grant create database link privilege to user who will own these tables. Something like, 

   `grant create database link to adnan;`
2. Login as that user now which will own the table and then create a private database link

`CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink
CONNECT TO [username at sourcedb] IDENTIFIED BY [sourcedb] user password>
USING '[remote_database_name_in_tnsnames.ora file or actual connect identifier]';`

using connection string directly instead of tnsnames.ora-
`CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink 
    CONNECT TO remote_user IDENTIFIED BY password
    USING '(DESCRIPTION=
                (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracledb.example.com)(PORT=1521))
                (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name))
            )';`

3. `create table <yourtablenmae> as select * from [table_name_at_sourcedb]@dblink where rownum<1;` --- This will create empty table if you want with data remove where condition.

Disclaimer: Haven't ran this so there might be some mistakes.